# Send a update and delete requests without refreshing frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send update and delete request without actually refreshing my frontend. So, I know that `e.preventDefault()` will prevent my frontend to refresh whenever I send in fetch request. However, I have to refresh the page to actually change the frontend after the request.

[My frontend looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1YXE.jpg)

[Image after clicking update button on the white card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNFGr.jpg)

What I want is to show the change within the frontend without refreshing the page. Also, I would like to pre-fill those textareas with values that already exist (I don't want to use placeholder). Please help.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function PostContainer({post}){
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
    const [title, setNewTitle] = useState("");
    const [content, setNewContent] = useState("");
    const [tags, setNewTags] = useState("");
    const userId = post.user_id

    console.log(post)

    function handleDelete(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(`/post/${post.id}`,{
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(post)
        })
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then(alert("Post Removed"))
    }

    // Display update component
    const handleUpdate = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsShown(current => !current)
    }

    // Send patch requests
    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const patchedPost = {
            title,
            content,
            userId,
            tags_attributes: tags.split(',').map((el) => { return {name: el} })
        }

        fetch(`/post/${post.id}`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(patchedPost)
        })
        .then((r)=>r.json())
        .then((x) => console.log(x)) 
    }
    
    return(
    <div>
        <div>
        {isShown && (
            <div>
                <form className='update-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Title</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text'  placeholder={post.title} value={title} onChange={(e)=>setNewTitle(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <label>Content</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text'  placeholder={post.content} value={content} onChange={(e)=>setNewContent(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <label>Tags</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text' placeholder={post.tags.name} value={tags} onChange={(e)=>setNewTags(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <button type='submit'>Update</button>
                    <button onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); setIsShown(false)}}>Cancel</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )}
        </div><br/>
        <div className='postContainer'>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p className="users-posts-content">{post.content}</p>
            <p>Tags: {post.tags.map((x)=> x.name).join(', ')}</p>
            <button onClick={(e)=>handleUpdate(e)}>Update</button> 
            <button onClick={(e)=>handleDelete(e)}>Delete Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `handleDelete()` method, you delete post by `id`, but after that you didnt refresh state of all your posts.

I'd do it something like that. In the `PostsContainer` I have GET-request which gets all posts, then updates state with all actual posts from the server via `setPosts()` and then re-render all posts on the page in a cycle:

```
//PostsContainer.jsx
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Post from './Post'

function PostsContainer() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
   getPosts()
  }, [])

  const getPosts = () => {
     fetch('/posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setPosts(json.posts))
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {
          posts 
            && posts.map(post => <Post key={post.id} post={post} getPosts={getPosts}/>)
        }
    </div>
  );
}
export default PostsContainer
```

And in Post.jsx I pass `getPosts()` method, which will call after I succefuly delete post:

```
//Post.jsx
function Post({ post, getPosts }) {
  
  const deletePost = (id) => {
    fetch(`/posts/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          getPosts()
        }
      })
      .catch(err => alert(err.message))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{post.id}</div>
      <div>{post.title}</div>
      <button onClick={() => deletePost(post.id)}>Delete post</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Post;
```

Thus, `getPosts()`, passed in Post.jsx, makes requests to the server, gets actual array of posts from db, then updates the state of all posts, then your posts will be re-rendered without page reloading